# How to get multiple line between two line in C# from txt file?

Tags: c#, file-handling

Hello everyone I have log file in which each exceptions are separated like

> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Demo:::: 24-0A-64-C7-E5-57 ::::  7/8/2015 6:54:37 PM ::::  Application
>   Info: DemoApp, Version=1.3.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
>   Error Message: Access to the path 'C:\ProgramData\Temp.txt' is denied.
>   at Line Number 95 in File Name
>   c:\Users\user\desktop\PC_CleanerDemo\App_Code\Global.cs in Function
>   Name UpateXML
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Demo:::: 0C-84-DC-1C-E8-23 ::::  7/8/2015 11:01:44 PM :::: 
>   Application Info: DemoApp, Version=1.3.1.1, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null Error Message: The operation has timed out. at
>   Line Number 189 in File Name
>   c:\Users\user\desktop\PC_CleanerDemo\App_Code\Global.cs in Function
>   Name DownloadFile.

In Above given lines each exceptions are separated by '-' character now as logs have numbers of lines now so I want to place different type of exception in different .txt file. I want solution in C#. If anyone can help I would be grateful to him.

Comment: Have you tried anything? This isn't a code writing service, its a "help you when you are stuck on something specific" site.

Comment: can you update the question with the code which use to write this log? and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends upon the log format.
If you have fix and equal no of '-' in each separator then do something like:

```
var sep = "------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------";
var logArray = LogText.Split(new string[] { sep  }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

and save each element of logArray in different files.

If you have varying no of '-' in separators and those are not in log text anywhere apart from separators then do something like:

```
while (logText.Contains("--"))
  logText = logText.Replace("--","-");
var logArray= logText.Split('-');
```

and save each element of logArray in different files or use regular expression. Please correct syntax in VS. Writing in notepad so not sure pasting it will work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Regex.Split`

```
string logText = @"-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Demo:::: 24-0A-64-C7-E5-57 :::: 7/8/2015 6:54:37 PM :::: Application Info: DemoApp, Version=1.3.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null Error Message: Access to the path 'C:\ProgramData\Temp.txt' is denied. at Line Number 95 in File Name c:\Users\user\desktop\PC_CleanerDemo\App_Code\Global.cs in Function Name UpateXML
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Demo:::: 0C-84-DC-1C-E8-23 :::: 7/8/2015 11:01:44 PM :::: Application Info: DemoApp, Version=1.3.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null Error Message: The operation has timed out. at Line Number 189 in File Name c:\Users\user\desktop\PC_CleanerDemo\App_Code\Global.cs in Function Name DownloadFile.";
            string patten = @"\s*-{50,}\s*";
            foreach (var str in Regex.Split(logText, patten))
            {
                if (str.Length > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("***************************");
                    Console.WriteLine(str);
                }
            }
```